# wp_set_post_terms is assigning only the last of several terms to a post

Tags: terms

I have this really simple setup where I loop through an array of actors, and for each actor name I successfully insert a term. Then I use wp_set_post_terms to assign the terms to a post, but this only assigns the last term to that post. I am new to using taxonomy/terms so maybe there's an obvious solution. Here's my code:

```
foreach ($cast as $actor) {

    $actor_term_id = wp_insert_term( $actor[name], 'actor', array(
        'description' => $bio[0]["desc"]
        )
    );

    // Assign term id to post
    wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $actor_term_id, 'actor' );

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need send a fourth argument to the function:

```
wp_set_post_terms($post_id, $actor_term_id, 'actor', true);
```

Each time the function executes, you're replacing any existing terms. The fourth argument specifies that you wish to append them.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_post_terms

Comment: I see, thanks. However, I noticed an issue: I can only assign an actor term to one post this way. If I use the function in a loop that has an actor name that was already added and assigned to a post before, it won't assign that term to another post...

Comment: I don't believe that this is an issue with WordPress, that's just how you chose to setup your loop. From WordPress' perspective, you can assign many terms to many posts.